# How to repeat form controls in asp.net mvc and pass them as a list to controller

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have 3 controls(one textbox, one numericbox and a date) inside a view form, these 3 forms the Model object. There is link provided to the user, on click of this link all the 3 controls were repeated 5 times inside the form.

I have a list of Model class  as an argument type in the controller action method. How to clone the form content 5 times such that it serializes properly to List?

Comment: In your Razor view use a `@for()` loop with a counter. Show us what you have attempted.

Comment: Refer answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29161481/post-a-form-array-without-successful/29161796#29161796) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308) for some options

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simpler way.

Model :

```
public class MyModel
{
    public IList<OneSetOfElements> FormSet { get; set; }
}

public class OneSetOfElements
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime Dob { get; set; }
}
```

Action :

```
public ActionResult MyAction(MyModel model)
{
    foreach (var set in model.FormSet)
    {
        //read your data.
    }
}
```

View : Show the id "showMeOnUrlClick" on click

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {

//This would bind as first list element
        <div id="firstSet"> 
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.FormSet[1].Name)
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.FormSet[1].Age)
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.FormSet[1].Dob, new { type = "date" })

        </div>

//Remaining list element
        <div id="showMeOnUrlClick" style="display: none"> 
            @for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
            {
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.FormSet[i].Name)
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.FormSet[i].Age)
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.FormSet[i].Dob, new {type = "date"})
            }
        </div>

        <button onclick="showTheRepeatedFields() ">Show</button>
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Shishir Kushwaha

Answer (score 2):

You should use jQuery to dynamically create a row with all the 3 input fields when user clicks on the Add button.

So in your razor view (ex:Create), create the first row with the three form fields.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
   <a href="#" id="addRow">Add</a>
   <div id="items">
      <div class="itemRow">
         <label>Name</label> <input type="text" class="formfield" name="Name" />
         <label>Age</label>  <input type="text" class="formfield" name="Age" />
         <label>CreateDate</label><input type="text" class="formfield" name="CreateDate" />
      </div>
   </div>
    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" />
}
```

Now we will add some client side code to listen to the `click` event on the Add link, create a clone of the container div(with css class `itemRow`) and append it to the outer container div(with id `items`). When user clicks the submit button, we will read the form fields and build an array of object and post that to the server using jQuery ajax.

```
@section Scripts
{
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

        $("#addRow").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();    
            var template = $("#items").find(".itemRow").first();
            var newRow = template.clone();
            newRow.find("input.formfield").val("");
            $("#items").append(newRow);

        });

        $("#btnSubmit").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var _this = $(this);
            var url =_this.closest("form").attr("action");

            var rows = [];
            var items = $(".itemRow");

            $.each(items, function (i, item) {                   
                var name =  $(item).find("input[name='Name']").val();
                var age =  $(item).find("input[name='Age']").val();
                var createDt =  $(item).find("input[name='CreateDate']").val();

                var row = { Name: name, Age: age, CreateDate: createDt };
                rows.push(row);    
            });

            //Let's post to server
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url: url,
                data: JSON.stringify(rows),
                contentType: "application/json"                       
            })
            .done(function (result) {
                //do something with the result
            })                 

        });    
    });    
</script>
}
```

Now you need an HttpPost action method to handle your form posting.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(IEnumerable<CreateUser> model)
{
    foreach(var item in model)
    {
        // to do  :Save
    }
    return Json( new { status ="success"});
}
```

and your `CreateUser` view model will look like

```
public class CreateUser
{
    public string Name { set;get;}
    public int Age { set; get; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { set; get; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer