# Return list of objects from ASP.NET MVC form

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC 5 app with C# and .NET Framework 4.5.1.

I want to create a dynamic form to allow users insert more fields if they need more. And then, when they submit the form retrieve this data on Controller.

This is my view:

```
@model List<TRZF.Web.API.Models.ProductViewModel>
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="~/css/common.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <link href="~/css/createBatch.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/css/createProduct.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/css/formStyles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/createProducts.js"></script>
    <title>Crear</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!----start-header----------->
    <div class="header_bg">
        <div class="wrap">
            <div class="header">
                <!--------start-logo------>
                <div class="logo">
                    <img src="~/images/logo.png" alt="" /><br />
                    <span>Versi&oacute;n 1.1</span>
                </div>  
                <!--------end-logo--------->
                <!----start-nav-------->    
                <div class="nav">

                </div>
                <!-----end-nav-------->
                <div class="clear"> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!------end-header------------>
    <div class="slider_bg">
        <div class="wrap">
            <div class="da-slide" style="padding:0%">
                @{
                using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "MyProduct", FormMethod.Post, new { name = "eProductsFrm", id = "eProductsFrm" }))
                {
                    <div>
                        <table class="productsList">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <h4>Producto</h4>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="group">
                                            <input type="text" 
                                                class="productClass"
                                                name="model[0].ProductName" 
                                                id="model[0].ProductName"
                                                required />
                                            @*<span class="highlight"></span>
                                            <span class="bar"></span>
                                            <label>Nombre del producto</label>*@
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                            <tfoot>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tfoot>
                        </table>
                        <table class="buttonsTable">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="text-align: left;">
                                    <input type="button" id="addrow" value="A&ntilde;adir producto" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="button" class="ibtnDel"  value="Borrar &uacute;ltimo producto">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>

                    <p><input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Crear producto(s)" /></p>
                }
                <div>
                    <p>@Html.ActionLink("Inicio", "Index", "Home")</p>
                </div>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that when I do submit, on Controller's method I get a null.

This is the controller:

```
public class MyProductController : Controller
{
    //
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(List<ProductViewModel> viewModel)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

How can I do to get something on MyProductController.Save method when the user click on Submit button?

Comment: So, your list is null when the page loads? And I don't see anything that puts any rows in it?

Comment: The list is null when the user submit data. I don't pass any data to this view. This is the first time I work with Razor and maybe this is the problem.

Comment: Ah, if you google asp mvc and tables you might find some good stuff.

Comment: Have a look at marked answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34230199/how-to-repeat-form-controls-in-asp-net-mvc-and-pass-them-as-a-list-to-controller/34237343#34237343

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this error with this html code:

```
<td>
    <div class="group">
        <input type="text" 
            class="productClass"
            name="[0].ProductName" 
            id="[0].ProductName"
            required />
        @*<span class="highlight"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <label>Nombre del producto</label>*@
    </div>
</td>
```

Now `name` and `id` are `[0].ProductName`.

More info [here](http://seesharpdeveloper.blogspot.com.es/2012/05/mvc-model-binding-to-list-of-complex.html).

Comment: Bare in mind that this may not work if you decide to add another parameter to the Save Action method. For this reason it is a better practice to bind the parameters by name.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have a typo here.. it should be as below:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "MyProduct", FormMethod.Post, new { name = "eProductsFrm", id = "eProductsFrm" }))
{
           // Your code
}
```

Comment: I was just writing this... hehe

Comment: Sorry, I had changed controller's name and I forget to changed it on the form. I have updated my question. Sorry.

Comment: can you show your ProductViewModel class ? @VansFannel

Answer (score 0):

In order for MVC to bind your form data to the Action method's parameters
their names should match.

In your case:

```
...
name="model[0].ProductName"
```

Should be:

```
...
name="viewModel[0].ProductName"
```

Because this is the name of the parameter that you have provided:

```
public ActionResult Save(List<ProductViewModel> viewModel)
```

Also be careful because the indexes should not be broken, which means that they should be 0, 1, 2.. etc. without skipping a number.

> The way that we read in the properties is by looking for
>   parameterName[index].PropertyName.  The index must be zero-based and
>   unbroken.

You can read more in Scott Hanselman's post - [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx)

Answer (score -2):

You are not linking model properties with your Html input properly.

Wrong:

```
<input type="text" class="productClass" name="model[0].ProductName" id="model[0].ProductName" required />
```

Right:

```
<input type="text" class="productClass" name="@Model[0].ProductName" id="@Model[0].ProductName" required />
```

Comment: not required as    everything is within    @{ ... }

Comment: This would give the input an id equal to the value of Model[0].ProductName whatever the name of that product is!

Comment: @{...} won't apply if a property name is inside the double quotes. Also model with small m can only be use for declaring a model.